# Does Blender support a uneven texture Sizes?

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

Hi is there a way to disable the auto-correcting it does.

For example a 1k-2k trim texture will always get unwrapped stretched by default(because Blender wants to compensate). If there's a way to turn it off that would be great.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the Aspect ratio to match the UV 0-1 space.

The UV coordinates have nothing to do with the image and the image will be confined to the 0-1 area. You will need to manually scale the UV coordinates in one axis to get an 1 by 1 pixel ratio on the model.

This is not specific for Blender.

[image]